# Can't connect to specific API from python code using 'requests' library

Tags: python, api, authentication, python-requests, csrf

I am trying to get my python code to connect to a specific API following below guide:

https://github.com/specify/specify7/wiki/API-Documentation-Demo

I can make it work from a Linux CLI as specified, but trying to emulate this process via python only yields 403 errors. Inspecting the request, I can see that the headers are set correctly and the data is actually parsed into the request body, so getting close, but so far no cigar.

```
#Connect to Specify7 API
# First step is to get a CSRF token 
csrftoken = requests.get(loginUrl).cookies.get('csrftoken')
print('CSRF Token: ', csrftoken)

# Next step is to use csrf token to log in 
headers = {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken, 'Referer' : baseUrl }
data = {"username" : "testy", "password" : "redacted", "collection": 4}
response = requests.put(loginUrl, json=data, headers=headers)

print('REQUEST: ', response.request.headers)
print('RESPONSE: ', response.status_code)
print(response.headers)
print()
print('***closer look at prepared request***')
print(response.request.method)
print(response.request.headers['Content-Type'])
print(response.request.headers['Referer'])
print(response.request.headers['X-CSRFToken'])
print(response.request.body)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `curl` client from the guide uses `-b` and `-c` options so that it handles cookies like a browser would do: The `csrftoken` cookie that is *received* with the GET request must be *sent* again with the subsequent PUT request. The header token is thus "bound" to the session cookie, for extra protection.

Your python code does behave like a browser in this regard. Your PUT request must additionally send a cookie named `csrftoken` whose value is the `csrftoken` variable.